# C# File.SetAccessControl Alternative for UWP

Tags: c#, file, uwp

UWP Apps don't offer this method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there a useful alternative in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a useful alternative in UWP?

The simple answer should be no.  [`File.SetAccessControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) method applies access control list (ACL) entries, the ACL assembly is marked with `UWPCompatible=false`, so that it is not supported in windows store app. Details please reference [UWP Compat](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/UWP-Compat#acl).